# Compilation error when I try compile MikTex

Tags: compiling, make

I've installed all dependencies needed to run `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"` command. This command is executed successfully. Next, I ran `make` command and I've get following error:

```
In file included from /home/hubert/Pobrane/miktex-2.9-2016-08-17/Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/source/dpxfile.c:39:0:
/home/hubert/Pobrane/miktex-2.9-2016-08-17/Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/source/dpxfile.c: In function ‘dpx_create_temp_file’:
/home/hubert/Pobrane/miktex-2.9-2016-08-17/Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/source/dpxfile.c:827:15: error: ‘_MAX_PATH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     tmp = NEW(_MAX_PATH + 1, char);
               ^
/home/hubert/Pobrane/miktex-2.9-2016-08-17/Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/source/mem.h:37:50: note: in definition of macro ‘NEW’
 #define NEW(n,type)     (type *) new(((uint32_t)(n))*sizeof(type))
                                                  ^
/home/hubert/Pobrane/miktex-2.9-2016-08-17/Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/source/dpxfile.c:827:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
     tmp = NEW(_MAX_PATH + 1, char);
               ^
/home/hubert/Pobrane/miktex-2.9-2016-08-17/Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/source/mem.h:37:50: note: in definition of macro ‘NEW’
 #define NEW(n,type)     (type *) new(((uint32_t)(n))*sizeof(type))
                                                  ^
Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-dvipdfmx.dir/build.make:206: polecenia dla obiektu 'Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-dvipdfmx.dir/source/dpxfile.c.o' nie powiodły się
make[2]: *** [Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-dvipdfmx.dir/source/dpxfile.c.o] Błąd 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3759: polecenia dla obiektu 'Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-dvipdfmx.dir/all' nie powiodły się
make[1]: *** [Programs/DviWare/dvipdfm-x/CMakeFiles/MiKTeX209-dvipdfmx.dir/all] Błąd 2
Makefile:149: polecenia dla obiektu 'all' nie powiodły się
make: *** [all] Błąd 2
```

I also get this error when I try compile MikTex using `sudo make`, `make install` and `sudo make install`. I've system Linux Mint 18 Sarah 64-bit on Toshiba Satellite C660D-102 computer. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The output tells that the variable _MAX_PATH is undeclared. Did you declare it? If not, you have to. Simple logic. You cannot give a function a variable without telling the program what value and what type of value it has.
If this isn't the case, post your code.